# Watir - ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby, watir

I'm trying Watir now, i have some Radio buttons and I a button to click after selecting the value.

```
<td>
    <input id="divPoll1" type="radio" value="1" name="Polls">
    <label for="divPoll2">Yes</label>
</td>
```

and

```
<td>
    <input id="divPoll2" type="radio" value="2" name="Polls">
    <label for="divPoll2">No</label>
</td>
```

Each time I try

```
>> browser.radio(:value => '2').set
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
    from (irb):48:in `radio'
    from (irb):48
    from :0
```

Any help ?

Comment: What version of Watir are you using? Based on the error, it sounds like an older version.

Comment: nevermind it worked with webdriver watir, thanks :)

Comment: People still use safariwatir?

Comment: n0idea, consider posting that switching over to webdriver waitr solved your problem and marking it as an answer. Its perfectly okay to mark your own questions as answered. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/posting-and-answering-questions-you-have-already-found-the-answer-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually switching over from SafariWatir worked perfectly fine. I tried webdriver-watir and works great.

Answer (score 2):

it depends on the version of WATIR you are using, the later versions supported using of fat commas(=>) for single attribute.

try browser.radio(:value, '2').set, the only time that I find fat comma works is when you use two attributes to identify an element eg. browser.radio(:value => '2', :id => 'divPolls2').set